# Testing AngularJS Services with Karma and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Okay...i have spent almost 3 hours trying to figure this out. I keep getting

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module

when trying to run my karma test. I have read other related questions and ordered the files properly but i am still getting that error. While i think the module function i need is coming from angular.mock.js file but it turns "inject" was also defined in that file and is being referenced as it should.

here are some important snippet that will show my situation better

karma.conf.js

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
      files: [
          'public/vendor/angular-1.2.0-rc2.js',
          'public/vendor/angular-test.js',
          'public/vendor/jasmine-helpers.js',
          'public/vendor/angular.mocks.js',
          'public/lib/**/*.js',
          'public/lib/*.js',
          'tests/*Spec.js'
      ],
```

spec file

```
describe("In the Weather Service Module", function(){

    var YWS, scope, mockWeatherService;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('NPWeatherWidget'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,_YahooWeatherService_){
        YWS = _YahooWeatherService_;
        scope = $rootScope;
        mockWeatherService = jasmine.createSpyObj('YahooWeatherService',['getwoeid','getData']);
        module(function($provide){
            $provide.value("YahooWeatherService",mockWeatherService);
        })
    }));

    //utility tests
    it("Object should be converted to query string", function(){
        console.log({name:"larry",age:20}.paramify());
        expect({name:"larry",age:20}.paramify()).toBe("name=larry&age=20");
    })
    it("should be converted to a query string", function(){
        expect(YWS).toBeDefined();
    });
    it("GetWoeID should return a bunch of objects with woeid included",function(done){
        expect({}).toBeDefined();
    });


});
```

Any form of pointer in the right direction will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `angular.mock.module('NPWeatherWidget')` just try `module('NPWeatherWidget')` in your `beforeEach` method.

Comment: Thanks @adamK, turns out the real issue was that i was using incompatible versions between my angular-mock.js and my actual angular file. When  i found the correct angular-mock.js file for angular 1.2.0-rc2 from code.angularjs.org, the problem went away